# Magento prices in decimals but only price .00 or price .99

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In magento for Bundled products I have Special prices in `%` because of which , all the bundled products have special prices like `133.05, 129.98, 233.23` so on ...

Ideally I would like to round this up to `133.00, 130.00(for 129.98) 233.00`.

I have found a way to do this round up by this, by changing precision to 0. But the problem with this is that it displays prices like `133` or `129` only while I would prefer `129.00` `133.00`, anything which is followed by `.99` like `129.99`. I would prefer to keep it as it is

Any way to fix this.This is what I tried.

```
code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php

public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$decimalPrice = 'your_price';
number_format($decimalPrice,2,".","");
```

Comment: where to put in this or replace ?

Answer (score -1):

Aus  I wanna know whether changi to this is safe for for paypal integration or not

code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php

```
public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets =       false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```